# x-editable - automatically initiate multiple select elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

My page contains multiple x-editable elements with data-type="select":

```
<a href="#" data-type="select" data-name="services_0" data-url="/customer/editfield" data-pk="1028" id="services_0">True</a>
<a href="#" data-type="select" data-name="services_1" data-url="/customer/editfield" data-pk="1028" id="services_1">False</a>
```

I'm trying to initiate them with x-editable with the following javascript code:

```
var services = ['services_0', 'services_1'];

    $.each(services, function(index, value) {
        $('#' + value).editable({
            prepend: 'Select one',
            source: [
            {
                value: 1,
                text: 'True'
            },
            {
                value: 0,
                text: 'False'
            }
            ],
            display: function(value, sourceData) {
                var colors = {
                    1: "green",
                    0: "blue"
                },
                elem = $.grep(sourceData, function(o) {
                    return o.value == value;
                });

                if (elem.length) {
                    $(this).text(elem[0].text).css("color", colors[value]);
                } else {
                    $(this).empty();
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

The problem is that it only binds the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the page source I found out that query $.grep was giving me a TypeError on e.length(). It triggered on 'value' on this line:

```
display: function(value, sourceData) {
```

Once i added data-value="" to the elements, everything was working as expected:

```
<a href="#" data-value="" data-type="select" data-name="services_0" data-url="/customer/editfield" data-pk="1028" id="services_0">True</a>
<a href="#" data-value="" data-type="select" data-name="services_1" data-url="/customer/editfield" data-pk="1028" id="services_1">False</a>
```